# Cluster Graph Visualization using python

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization

I am assembling different visualization tools that are available in python language. I found the Treemap. (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/treemap/1.05)

Can you suggest some other tools that are available. I am exploring different ways of visualization of web data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would be ok with using jython there are some good visualization libraries for java including:

1. [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org)
2. [Piccolo](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/jazz/)

If you are using Python on the server and want to use Javascript or Flash there are other libraries available

Javascript:

1. [Javascript InfovisToolkit](http://thejit.org/)
2. [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)
3. [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)

Flash:

1. [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/)

Answer (score 4):

The [Nodebox Graph](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph) library is specifically designed for graph visualization and analysis: well worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

You could try NetworkX:
(http://networkx.lanl.gov/)

It's really simple to use and supports either matplotlib or Graphviz for graphics.
The documentation is excellent too.

Comment: However NetworkX's use of Matplotlib renders MultiGraphs [overlaying edges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053686/networkx-overlapping-edges-when-visualizing-multigraph) which connect the same two nodes. For exporting or plotting within Python, this can be overcome by calling [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/) in the background, via [NetworkX.to_pydot](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot.html, provided [Pydot](https://code.google.com/p/pydot/) is available. But for interactive visualization/animation within Python this is not a descent solution.

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib is a great tool for visualization. and mayaVi for 3d visualization.
pygl and pyglet for a bit lower graphics, otherwise!