# Drawing multiple edges between two nodes with networkx

Tags: python, graph, label, networkx, edges

I need to draw a directed graph with more than one edge (with different weights) between two nodes. That is, I have nodes A and B and edges (A,B) with length=2 and (B,A) with length=3.

I have tried both using G=nx.Digraph and G=nx.Multidigraph. When I draw it, I only get to view one edge and only one of the labels.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053686/networkx-overlapping-edges-when-visualizing-multigraph and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943439/how-to-draw-multigraph-in-networkx-using-matplotlib-or-graphviz for info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340520/matplotlib-and-networkx-drawing-a-self-loop-node

Answer (score 34):

Here is how to get an outcome similar to the following:
[image: Final graph]

Some properties of this are:

- When there is a single edge between two nodes, it is straight.
- Labels are positioned perfectly in the middle of the edges.
- The current solution works for DiGraphs only. MultiGraphs, MultiDiGraphs, and self loops are not supported.

## Setting it up

The following lines are initial code to start the example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
edge_list = [(1,2,{'w':'A1'}),(2,1,{'w':'A2'}),(2,3,{'w':'B'}),(3,1,{'w':'C'}),
             (3,4,{'w':'D1'}),(4,3,{'w':'D2'}),(1,5,{'w':'E1'}),(5,1,{'w':'E2'}),
             (3,5,{'w':'F'}),(5,4,{'w':'G'})]
G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
pos=nx.spring_layout(G,seed=5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=ax)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, ax=ax)
fig.savefig("1.png", bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0)
```

Which results in:

[image: Graph with only nodes]

## Drawing edges

The `draw_networkx_edges` function of NetworkX is able to draw only a subset of the edges with the `edgelist` parameter. To use this, we group the edges into two lists and draw them separately. Thanks to [AMangipinto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59917339) for `connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1'`.

```
curved_edges = [edge for edge in G.edges() if reversed(edge) in G.edges()]
straight_edges = list(set(G.edges()) - set(curved_edges))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=ax, edgelist=straight_edges)
arc_rad = 0.25
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=ax, edgelist=curved_edges, connectionstyle=f'arc3, rad = {arc_rad}')
fig.savefig("2.png", bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0)
```

Which results in:

[image: Graph without labels]

## Drawing edge labels

The `draw_networkx_edge_labels` function of NetworkX assumes the edges to be straight and there is no parameter to change this. Since NetworkX is open-souce, I copied the function and created a modified `my_draw_networkx_edge_labels`. This function is down at the appendix.

Assuming you save this function to a file called my_networkx.py, you can draw edge labels as:

```
import my_networkx as my_nx
edge_weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'w')
curved_edge_labels = {edge: edge_weights[edge] for edge in curved_edges}
straight_edge_labels = {edge: edge_weights[edge] for edge in straight_edges}
my_nx.my_draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, ax=ax, edge_labels=curved_edge_labels,rotate=False,rad = arc_rad)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, ax=ax, edge_labels=straight_edge_labels,rotate=False)
fig.savefig("3.png", bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0)
```

Where we once again seperated curved from straight. The result is the first figure in this answer.

## Appendix

The function `draw_networkx_edge_labels` of NetworkX finds the positions of the labels assuming straight lines:

```
(x, y) = (
    x1 * label_pos + x2 * (1.0 - label_pos),
    y1 * label_pos + y2 * (1.0 - label_pos),
)
```

To find the middle point of a quadratic Bezier curve we can use the following code. First we find the middle control point (`ctrl_1` in the code) of the Bezier curve according to the definition in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionStyle.html#matplotlib.patches.ConnectionStyle.Arc3):

> The curve is created so that the middle control point (C1) is located
> at the same distance from the start (C0) and end points(C2) and the
> distance of the C1 to the line connecting C0-C2 is rad times the
> distance of C0-C2.

Due to this definition, the function `my_draw_networkx_edge_labels` requires an extra parameter called `rad`.

```
pos_1 = ax.transData.transform(np.array(pos[n1]))
pos_2 = ax.transData.transform(np.array(pos[n2]))
linear_mid = 0.5*pos_1 + 0.5*pos_2
d_pos = pos_2 - pos_1
rotation_matrix = np.array([(0,1), (-1,0)])
ctrl_1 = linear_mid + rad*rotation_matrix@d_pos
```

The functions starting with "ax.transData" are necessary since 90 degree angles in the axis domain do not correspond to 90 degrees in the display. So we had to transform coordinates to and from the display coordinate system.

`bezier_mid` can be calculated with Bezier curve rules:

```
ctrl_mid_1 = 0.5*pos_1 + 0.5*ctrl_1
ctrl_mid_2 = 0.5*pos_2 + 0.5*ctrl_1
bezier_mid = 0.5*ctrl_mid_1 + 0.5*ctrl_mid_2
(x, y) = ax.transData.inverted().transform(bezier_mid)
```

Complete `my_draw_networkx_edge_labels`:

```
def my_draw_networkx_edge_labels(
    G,
    pos,
    edge_labels=None,
    label_pos=0.5,
    font_size=10,
    font_color="k",
    font_family="sans-serif",
    font_weight="normal",
    alpha=None,
    bbox=None,
    horizontalalignment="center",
    verticalalignment="center",
    ax=None,
    rotate=True,
    clip_on=True,
    rad=0
):
    """Draw edge labels.

    Parameters
    ----------
    G : graph
        A networkx graph

    pos : dictionary
        A dictionary with nodes as keys and positions as values.
        Positions should be sequences of length 2.

    edge_labels : dictionary (default={})
        Edge labels in a dictionary of labels keyed by edge two-tuple.
        Only labels for the keys in the dictionary are drawn.

    label_pos : float (default=0.5)
        Position of edge label along edge (0=head, 0.5=center, 1=tail)

    font_size : int (default=10)
        Font size for text labels

    font_color : string (default='k' black)
        Font color string

    font_weight : string (default='normal')
        Font weight

    font_family : string (default='sans-serif')
        Font family

    alpha : float or None (default=None)
        The text transparency

    bbox : Matplotlib bbox, optional
        Specify text box properties (e.g. shape, color etc.) for edge labels.
        Default is {boxstyle='round', ec=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fc=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)}.

    horizontalalignment : string (default='center')
        Horizontal alignment {'center', 'right', 'left'}

    verticalalignment : string (default='center')
        Vertical alignment {'center', 'top', 'bottom', 'baseline', 'center_baseline'}

    ax : Matplotlib Axes object, optional
        Draw the graph in the specified Matplotlib axes.

    rotate : bool (deafult=True)
        Rotate edge labels to lie parallel to edges

    clip_on : bool (default=True)
        Turn on clipping of edge labels at axis boundaries

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        `dict` of labels keyed by edge

    Examples
    --------
    >>> G = nx.dodecahedral_graph()
    >>> edge_labels = nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G))

    Also see the NetworkX drawing examples at
    https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/auto_examples/index.html

    See Also
    --------
    draw
    draw_networkx
    draw_networkx_nodes
    draw_networkx_edges
    draw_networkx_labels
    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    if edge_labels is None:
        labels = {(u, v): d for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True)}
    else:
        labels = edge_labels
    text_items = {}
    for (n1, n2), label in labels.items():
        (x1, y1) = pos[n1]
        (x2, y2) = pos[n2]
        (x, y) = (
            x1 * label_pos + x2 * (1.0 - label_pos),
            y1 * label_pos + y2 * (1.0 - label_pos),
        )
        pos_1 = ax.transData.transform(np.array(pos[n1]))
        pos_2 = ax.transData.transform(np.array(pos[n2]))
        linear_mid = 0.5*pos_1 + 0.5*pos_2
        d_pos = pos_2 - pos_1
        rotation_matrix = np.array([(0,1), (-1,0)])
        ctrl_1 = linear_mid + rad*rotation_matrix@d_pos
        ctrl_mid_1 = 0.5*pos_1 + 0.5*ctrl_1
        ctrl_mid_2 = 0.5*pos_2 + 0.5*ctrl_1
        bezier_mid = 0.5*ctrl_mid_1 + 0.5*ctrl_mid_2
        (x, y) = ax.transData.inverted().transform(bezier_mid)

        if rotate:
            # in degrees
            angle = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) / (2.0 * np.pi) * 360
            # make label orientation "right-side-up"
            if angle > 90:
                angle -= 180
            if angle < -90:
                angle += 180
            # transform data coordinate angle to screen coordinate angle
            xy = np.array((x, y))
            trans_angle = ax.transData.transform_angles(
                np.array((angle,)), xy.reshape((1, 2))
            )[0]
        else:
            trans_angle = 0.0
        # use default box of white with white border
        if bbox is None:
            bbox = dict(boxstyle="round", ec=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fc=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
        if not isinstance(label, str):
            label = str(label)  # this makes "1" and 1 labeled the same

        t = ax.text(
            x,
            y,
            label,
            size=font_size,
            color=font_color,
            family=font_family,
            weight=font_weight,
            alpha=alpha,
            horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment,
            verticalalignment=verticalalignment,
            rotation=trans_angle,
            transform=ax.transData,
            bbox=bbox,
            zorder=1,
            clip_on=clip_on,
        )
        text_items[(n1, n2)] = t

    ax.tick_params(
        axis="both",
        which="both",
        bottom=False,
        left=False,
        labelbottom=False,
        labelleft=False,
    )

    return text_items
```

Comment: It could be cool to add an application for self loops too but good job!

Answer (score 29):

An improvement to the reply above is adding the [connectionstyle](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionStyle.html) to nx.draw, this allows to see two parallel lines in the plot:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph() #or G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_node('A')
G.add_node('B')
G.add_edge('A', 'B', length = 2)
G.add_edge('B', 'A', length = 3)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1')
edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['length'])
             for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])

plt.show()
```

[image: See here the result]

Comment: Maybe you can check answer from Francesco Sgaramella on this same post, he was adding also labels to the plot.

Comment: thanks your answer helped. The answer by Francesco Sgaramella is helpful to show the weights on edges but it shows only the weights for A -> B and not the one for B-> A, any suggestion how to show both? did you solve your problem? @mdexp

Comment: @nooshinha it worked fine for me by using the `connectionstyle` param from this answer and the `nx.draw_networkx_edge_label` from Francesco's answer. I had to tweak the `label_pos` parameter because weigths were overlapping in the middle and only one was shown (but there were actually two one on top of the other).

Comment: Unfortunately I did not manage to place the label on top of the corresponding arch, but my solution was enough for my problem

Comment: @mdexp Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand that the overlap between weight labels is the problem and not the values. Although your problem is solved but in case I solve the solution I will share it here.

Answer (score 12):

Try the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph() #or G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_node('A')
G.add_node('B')
G.add_edge('A', 'B', length = 2)
G.add_edge('B', 'A', length = 3)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos)
edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['length'])
             for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, label_pos=0.3, font_size=7)
plt.show()
```

This will return you this graph with two edges and the length shown on the edge:

[image]

Comment: This is possibly the worst enemy when it comes to visualizing and reading weighted graphs. It's ugy, unreadable, and in directed graph - hell knows which edge is which.

Comment: what is the difference between length and weight?

Answer (score 6):

You can use matplotlib directly using the node positions you have calculated.

```
G=nx.MultiGraph ([(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(3,1),(3,2)])
pos = nx.random_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color = 'r', node_size = 100, alpha = 1)
ax = plt.gca()
for e in G.edges:
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=pos[e[0]], xycoords='data',
                xytext=pos[e[1]], textcoords='data',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color="0.5",
                                shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                                patchA=None, patchB=None,
                                connectionstyle="arc3,rad=rrr".replace('rrr',str(0.3*e[2])
                                ),
                                ),
                )
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how do you add the edge label (text) for each arrow?

Comment: This is pure gold. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to AMangipinto's solution to add edge labels in both directions (see link for picture):

```
edge_labels = dict([((u, v,), f'{d["length"]}\n\n{G.edges[(v,u)]["length"]}')
                for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True) if pos[u][0] > pos[v][0]])

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, font_color='red')
```

The "if pos[u][0] > pos[v][0]" only adds an edge label in one direction. We add both lengths to the single label otherwise we would over write the first label on an edge.
Note: The label won't show if the nodes have the same x position.

[image: plot with edge labels]

Comment: This only works if the curvature of the arc is very small.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There are two common ways to draw bi-directional edges between two nodes:

1. Draw both edges as straight lines, each parallel to but slightly offset from the direct line connecting the nodes.
2. Draw both edges as curved lines; ensure that they arc in different directions.
   In both cases, labels can simply be placed at the centre of the two lines.

Both approaches don't mesh well with the current state of the `networkx` drawing utilities:

1. The first approach requires a good choice of offset between the
   parallel edges. Common choices in other libraries include the
   average edge width or a third of the node size. However, node
   positions in `networkx` are given in data coordinates whereas node
   sizes and edge widths are given in display coordinates. This makes
   computation of the offset cumbersome, and -- more importantly --
   the layout breaks if the figure is resized (as the transformation
   from data coordinates to display coordinates changes).
2. As outlined in other answers, `networkx` can draw curved edges by
   setting the correct `connectionstyle`. However, this feature was
   added relatively recently to networkx and hence the function that
   draws the labels still assumes straight edges. If the edges only
   have a very small arc (i.e. are still basically straight), then the
   labels can be fudged to the approximate correct positions by adding
   newline characters in the right places to the labels, as
   demonstrated by @PaulMenzies answer. However, this approach
   generally yields suboptimal results and breaks if the curvature is
   high.

If you are open to use other plotting utilities built on `matplotlib`,
I have an implementation of both approaches in my module
[netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph). `netgraph` is
fully compatible with networkx and igraph Graph objects, so it should
be easy and fast to generate good looking graphs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

from netgraph import Graph # pip install netgraph

triangle = nx.DiGraph([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'c')])

node_positions = {
    'a' : np.array([0.2, 0.2]),
    'b' : np.array([0.8, 0.2]),
    'c' : np.array([0.5, 0.8]),
}

edge_labels = {
    ('a', 'b') : 3,
    ('a', 'c') : 'Lorem ipsum',
    ('b', 'a') : 4,
    ('c', 'b') : 'dolor sit',
    ('c', 'c') : r'$\pi$'
}

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14,14))

Graph(triangle, node_labels=True, edge_labels=edge_labels,
      edge_label_fontdict=dict(size=12, fontweight='bold'),
      node_layout=node_positions, edge_layout='straight',
      node_size=6, edge_width=4, arrows=True, ax=ax1)

Graph(triangle, node_labels=True, edge_labels=edge_labels,
      edge_label_fontdict=dict(size=12, fontweight='bold'),
      node_layout=node_positions, edge_layout='curved',
      node_size=6, edge_width=4, arrows=True, ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Sadly, the labels and the curves are not working for me, it looks like it is all merged together.

Comment: @satk0 If you raise an issue with a minimal reproducible example on my [github](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/issues/), then I will look into it.