# Counting edges between nodes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph where my nodes can have multiple edges between them in both directions and I want to set the width between the nodes based on the sum of all edges between them.

```
import networkx as nx
nodes = [0,1]
edges = [(0,1),(1,0)]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
weights = [2,3]
nx.draw(G, width = weights)
```

I would like to have the width between 0 and 1 set to 5 as that is the summed weight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [networkx - change color/width according to edge attributes - inconsistent result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639169/networkx-change-color-width-according-to-edge-attributes-inconsistent-result)

Comment: At the very least, you'll need to change how you create your graphs.  A networkx `Graph` is undirected and has at most 1 edge.  It simply ignores the second time you add an edge.  Try a `MultiGraph` to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to create a `MultiDiGraph` and add all possible edges to it. This is because it supports multiple directed egdes between the same set of nodes including self-loops.

```
import networkx as nx
nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
edges = [(0,1), (1,0), (1, 0),(0, 1), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2, 3),
         (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 1), (4, 5), (5, 0)]
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

Next, create a dictionary containing counts of each edges

```
from collections import Counter
width_dict = Counter(G.edges())
edge_width = [ (u, v, {'width': value}) 
              for ((u, v), value) in width_dict.items()]
```

Now create a new `DiGraph` from the `edge_width` dictionary created above

```
G_new = nx.DiGraph()
G_new.add_edges_from(edge_width)
```

**Plotting using thickened edges**

This is an extension of answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25651827/8160718).

```
edges = G_new.edges()
weights = [G_new[u][v]['width'] for u,v in edges] 
nx.draw(G_new, edges=edges, width=weights)
```

[image]

**Add Edge labels**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22862610/8160718) for more info.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G_new)
nx.draw(G_new, pos)
edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['width'])
             for u,v,d in G_new.edges(data=True)])

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G_new, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G_new, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels,
                             label_pos=0.25, font_size=10)
```

[image]

You can also view [this Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13fxmzzcVWSjZTBci4r4RyzF_TFSaLkQj) with working code.

**References**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25651827/8160718
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22862610/8160718
- [Drawing networkX edges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges)
- [MultiDiGraph in NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/classes.multidigraph.html#multidigraph-directed-graphs-with-self-loops-and-parallel-edges)
- [Count occurrences of List items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909767/8160718)