# Generating Directed Graph With Parallel Labelled Edges/Vertices in Python

Tags: python, graph, currency, directed-graph

What is the best way to generate a Directed Graph With Parallel Labelled Edges/Vertices in Python like the one in the Image below??

I have already tried networkx but it does not work with parallel edges.

[image]

This is the code I'm using to generate the data for the Graph.

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
import pandas as pd

chosen_currencies = ['GBP', 'EUR', 'USD']

c = CurrencyRates()

rates = []


for currency_index in range(len(chosen_currencies)):
    temp_list = []
    for second_index in range(len(chosen_currencies)):
        temp_list.append(c.get_rate(chosen_currencies[currency_index], chosen_currencies[second_index]))
    rates.append(temp_list)

df = (pd.DataFrame.from_records(rates)).transpose()
df.columns = chosen_currencies
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dataframe to read the edges directly into a NetworkX graph using [from_pandas_adjacency](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_adjacency.html). In order to do that, lets set the index of the `dataframe` equal to `chosen_currencies`, to ensure that the edges are mapped correctly.

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
import pandas as pd

chosen_currencies = ['GBP', 'EUR', 'USD']

c = CurrencyRates()

rates = []


for currency_index in range(len(chosen_currencies)):
    temp_list = []
    for second_index in range(len(chosen_currencies)):
        temp_list.append(c.get_rate(chosen_currencies[currency_index], chosen_currencies[second_index]))
    rates.append(temp_list)

df = (pd.DataFrame.from_records(rates)).transpose()
df.columns = chosen_currencies
#   GBP         EUR     USD
#0  1.000000    0.83238 0.768233
#1  1.201374    1.00000 0.922935
#2  1.301689    1.08350 1.000000
```

Now set the index

```
df.set_index([pd.Index(chosen_currencies)], inplace=True)
#       GBP         EUR     USD
#GBP    1.000000    0.83238 0.768233
#EUR    1.201374    1.00000 0.922935
#USD    1.301689    1.08350 1.000000
```

Now let's create the graph

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df, create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# Set the figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

# Get the edge labels and round them to 3 decimal places
# for more clarity while drawing
edge_labels = dict([((u,v), round(d['weight'], 3))
             for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])

# Get the layout
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# Draw edge labels and graph
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels,
                             label_pos=0.15, font_size=10)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True,
        connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.15',
        node_size=800)

plt.show()
```

[image: Currency Graph]

**Note:** The number near the arrowhead is the edge weight.

You can also view [this Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mwSGFGh-yF-RXT_0oclGEmrIor5qpCQq) with above working example.

You can adjust the font size, label position, etc. according to your requirements.

**References:**

- [Connection Style](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionStyle.html)
- [Draw Edge Labels](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html)
- [Drawing multiple edge labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22862610/8160718)

Comment: I'm trying to find which parameter puts the weights over the edges like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQqOQ.png). Have you got any idea? The Graph gets quite messy when I add more nodes. [This](https://ibb.co/VJhvqd3) Is what I generated and it does not look very readable.

Comment: Dense graphs like that are better visualized using tables.