# Directed Graph Structure in networkx with two edges between two nodes

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am looking to have two directed edges connecting two nodes going in opposite directions. Currently I have the following, but it only shows one edge with two arrows.

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

abc=[n1 for n1 in itertools.permutations([1,2,3],2)]
G1 = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G1.add_edges_from(abc)
nx.draw_networkx(G1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here: [Drawing multiple edges between two nodes with networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785849/drawing-multiple-edges-between-two-nodes-with-networkx)

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

abc=[n1 for n1 in itertools.permutations([1,2,3],2)]
G1 = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G1.add_edges_from(abc)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G1)
nx.draw_networkx(G1,pos,with_labels=True,connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1')
plt.show()
```