How to add two different weighted edges between 2 nodes using networkx
I am trying to have two directional edges between nodes 'x' and 'w' of different weights. This is what I currently have with the following code:
graph2 = nx.MultiDiGraph()
graph2.add_nodes_from(["w", "x", "y", "z"])
graph2.add_weighted_edges_from(
[("x", "w", 2), ("z", "x", 2), ("x", "y", 3), ("y", "y", 2), ("w", "y", 1), ("w", "w", 
1), ("w", "z", 5), ("w", "x", 4)]
)

node_positions = {"x": (0, 0), "w": (2, 0), "y": (2, -2), "z": (0, 2)}
nx.draw(graph2, pos=node_positions, with_labels=True, node_color="pink", 
node_size=2000)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(graph2, "weight")
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(graph2, pos=node_positions, edge_labels=edge_labels)

plt.show()


How do I get a double edge between x and w, showing both of their respective weights?
Edit: this is the graph I was meant to recreate for the exercise


Networkx doesn't support multiedge labels with the default plotting. You might want to use graphviz.

This link might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785849/drawing-multiple-edges-between-two-nodes-with-networkx
