# networkx: how to draw multiple lines/edges between 2 fixed points

Tags: python, graph, draw, networkx

i'm a newbie to networkx world. it looks really cool, but would like to know if there's a way to draw, networking-related diagram, such as below:

```
           +--------------+
     +---->+  Controller  +<----+
     |     +--------------+     |
     |                          |
     |                          |
     |                          |
    sw-a   =================   sw-b
```

so far, of all the examples/galleries i find on the net only show 1 edge between two fixed nodes. in network topologies, it's very common to have multi-links between nodes. 
how am i going to achieve this?
i tried (focus only on sw-a and sw-b):

```
G.add_edge('sw-a','sw-b',weight=0.6)
G.add_edge('sw-a','sw-b',weight=0.2)
elarge=[('sw-a', 'sw-b')]
esmall=[('sw-a', 'sw-b')]
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=elarge,width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=esmall,width=2,alpha=0.5,\
     edge_color='b',style='dashed')
```

but the lines drawn are not being split and separated (parallel-lines), instead they're overlapping with each other.
any hints would be appreciated.
tia.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15053686 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10419646. In short: neato can draw multi-edge graphs but the feature has not been implemented in networkx (yet)

Comment: It might be a good idea to increase the thickness of the drawn edge depending on how many edges between the 2 nodes