# Curved edges using matplotlib and Networkx in Python 3.x

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I want to draw curved edges using the Networkx framework and matplotlib.

Basically the same problem as linked below:

[Networkx: Overlapping edges when visualizing MultiGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053686/networkx-overlapping-edges-when-visualizing-multigraph)

One answer is:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([0,1])
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1', node_color = 'r', node_size = 100, alpha = 1)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos,connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1', edgelist = [(0,1)], width = 2, alpha = 0.5, edge_color='b')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos,connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1', edgelist= [(1,0)], width = 1, alpha = 1)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

But that produces:

[image]

In the end I want to produce something like this:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/beyondbeneath/bezier-curved-edges-networkx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly with networkx functions. But you can use matplotlib directly using the node positions you have calculated.

E.g. based on [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/userdemo/connectionstyle_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-connectionstyle-demo-py):

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([0,1])
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color = 'r', node_size = 100, alpha = 1)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate("",
                xy=pos[0], xycoords='data',
                xytext=pos[1], textcoords='data',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color="0.5",
                                shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                                patchA=None, patchB=None,
                                connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.3",
                                ),
                )
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Gives:

[image]